# Add sitemap on external server to Django Sitemap

Tags: django, wordpress, sitemap

Django has a [built-in Sitemap class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/) to generate a `sitemap.xml` from the urls it contains (well - the user has pointed to). That's great. But my blog to my web app (which is on e.g. `mysite.com`) is hosted on a different server and run using WordPress. The blog URL is `blog.mysite.com`.

My question is: is there a way to use the django built-in sitemap class to add this external url (`blog.mysite.com`) to the generated `sitemap.xml`? If not - what is the best way to create the sitemap file? Wordpress also generates a sitemap on its own, so I need a reference in the django generated `sitemap.xml` pointing to the WP `sitemap.xml`. But how to link those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with a custom `Sitemap` subclass, but you shouldn't.

See [Sitemap.org FAQ](https://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_sitemap_location):

> **Q: Where do I place my Sitemap?**
>
> [...]
>
> All URLs listed in the Sitemap must reside on the same host as the
>   Sitemap. For instance, if the Sitemap is located at
>   http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml, it can't include URLs from
>   http://subdomain.example.com. [...]

Comment: AAAaaah. I didn't know that! How does googlebot deal with this?

Comment: I am not an SEO expert, but it should be enough to have a link from `mysite.com` to `blog.mysite.com` and Google will figure out the rest. Just make sure you don't accidentally deny crawling in any of your  `robots.txt`  files